# Google Analytics Multi-domains Tracking Code

Tags: google-analytics, cross-domain

I have the same GA code on 2 domains that I'm trying to track: domain.com and domain.de. Do I need to add  setAllowLinker and setDomainName in both domains? Both sites are under the same account/profile but using hostname filter.﻿

(the sites won't link between each other)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the sites do not link between each other you don't need a special setup - the linker functions maintain sessions between domains (which is not possible with cookies, so the session data is transmitted via Url) and setDomainName sets the cookie domains, which likewise is not necessary in your case.

I do not understand you second question. If you have created a second data view / profile for you com-Domain it starts at 0 visits (pageviews etc) because the view collects data only from the moment it was created, which might be your problem here (plus I think the etiquette at stack overflow suggests to have only one question per Post, so you might edit the seconds question out and put it in a second post).